# DataTable Select on camel case string not working correctly

Tags: c#, select, datatable, case-sensitive, camelcasing

I am performing a search on a `DataTable` and am getting unexpected results. The table contains a column called Name. One of the rows contains the value `"MustHaveRings"` for the Name column.

Both the `DataSet` and `DataTable` have the `CaseSensitive` property set to false which should perform a case-insensitive search.

When I perform the search with the following, no rows are returned which is unexpected.

```
string input = "musthaverings";
var foundRows = ds.Tables[5].Select("Name= '" + input + "'");
```

After experimenting with different combinations of uppercase and lowercase characters in the string I get the following results

```
string input = "MustHaveRings";//1 row returned
string input = "Musthaverings";//no rows returned
string input = "MustHaverings";//1 row returned
string input = "mustHaveRings";//1 row returned
string input = "mustHaverings";//1 row returned
string input = "musthaveRings";//no rows returned
string input = "MUSTHAVERINGS";//no rows returned
```

I have been searching for a couple of days now on why I get these results but cannot find the answer. With the same scenarios I have also tried using `string.Compare()` with `ignoreCase` set to `false` which brings back the same results.

I feel like I am over looking something but just cannot work it out. I'm using .NET 4.0.

Can anyone explain the logic as to how the equality operator works in this situation?

**Additional info:**

The data is retrieved from a stored procedure from a SqlServer database. Below are a few examples of the rows I get back:

```
----------------------------------------------
| TypeID| Parent |     Name    | ForOrderOnly |
----------------------------------------------
|  375  |        |  Lighten Up |     357      |
----------------------------------------------
|  429  |        |MustHaveRings|     429      |
----------------------------------------------
|  231  |   257  |  One Pound  |     385      |
----------------------------------------------
|  385  |   257  |  Shop Edit  |     385      |
```

Not sure if this helps but `Name` column stores the value as a `varchar` with Collation set to `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`

I carried out the test again with only one row that contains the Name "MustHaveRings" and got the same results

Comment: @Wade73: This is in a `DataTable`. It is in-memory. There is no SQL.

Comment: Could you please post the data stored in `Tables[5]` (column types, few other rows)?

Comment: @JohnSaunders I should have paid a bit more attention before asking my question.  Thanks.

Comment: Try a test case where there is only a single row in the `DataTable`, containing "MustHaveRings" in the Name column. No other rows. Then try your tests of different casing. This will rule out whether there are other rows which actually contain the other values of Name. Not so much for you, but for the readers.

Comment: Do you set `CaseSensitive` attribute before or after you fill the `DataSet`?

Comment: @mrtig The `CaseSensitive` attribute is not set before the fill but it defaults to false anyway. I tried setting it to false before the fill to see if that affects the outcome butI still get the same results

Comment: So, if you set `CaseSensitive` to `true`, your test should only return a row when `string input = "MustHaveRings";` and none otherwise. Is this true?

Comment: @mrtig Yes that is correct I just tested it to be sure

Comment: And what happens when you set up your table like this: `DataTable datatbl = new DataTable(); datatbl.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string)); datatbl.Rows.Add(new string[] { "MustHaveRings" });`

Comment: @mrtig I've setup the table as you've suggested but still get the same results